# Guardar uma imagem identificando-a a partir do FrameworkElement

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho este layout:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Click="button_Click" Height="50" />
    <Image x:Name="image" Source="vermelho.jpg" />
</StackPanel>
```

O código que testei para gravar a imagem para um ficheiro png é o seguinte:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
    dlg.FileName = "imagem";
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".png";
    dlg.Filter = "Imagem PNG (.png)|*.png";
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
    if (result == true)
    {
        var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        SaveUsingEncoder(image, dlg.FileName, encoder);
    }
}

void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName, BitmapEncoder encoder)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)visual.ActualWidth,
        (int)visual.ActualHeight,
        96,
        96,
        PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bitmap.Render(visual);
    BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
    encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
    using (var stream = File.Create(fileName))
    {
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

Porque razão é que quando abro a imagem gravada no disco, também é gravada, em transparente, a área correspondente ao botão?

Answer (score 2):

Para te ajudar reproduzi aqui seu problema e fiz um resumo do que entendi.

RESUMO: O que parece acontecer, é que a classe `RenderTargetBitmap`, mesmo com o método "Render" contendo o Visual especificado sua medidas definidas de acordo com o alvo. ele não se posiciona corretamente para transformar o alvo em um Bitmap. É como se ele formasse um quadrado posicionado no inicio da Janela ao invés de ficar sobre a imagem. Não sei o motivo disso acontecer, estou pesquisando.

Ademais, consegui solucionar o problema colocando a imagem dentro de um `DrawingVisual`.

```
 public void SaveUsingEncoder(FrameworkElement visual, string fileName)
 {
        // SOLUÇÃO DO PROBLEMA: Colocar a imagem dentro de um DrawingVisual que é uma classe de desenho.
        DrawingVisual drawing = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext ctx = drawing.RenderOpen())
        {
            VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(visual);
            ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(visual.Width, visual.Height)));
        }

        // Cria uma nova instância do RenderTargetBitmap onde será convertido um alvo visual para bitmap.
        RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)visual.Width, (int)visual.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        // Converte o DrawingVisual com sua imagem em Bitmap
        bitmap.Render(drawing);

        // Cria instância do encode
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        // Transforma nosso BitmapSource em uma imagem
        BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
        // Adiciona a imagem ao encoder. Transformando ela em PNG...
        encoder.Frames.Add(frame);

        using (var file = File.Create(fileName))
        {
            encoder.Save(file);
        }
    }
```

Não sei ao certo se essa é a solução ideal e até mesmo se o que eu disse sobre o `RenderTargetBitmap` está certo. Caso alguém tenha uma explicação melhor, nos ajude a entender essa situação.

Answer (score 0):

Eu entretanto abandonei esta abordagem e resolvi assim, de forma mais simples:

```
//Criar um ficheiro no disco correspondente à imagem exibida na área de preview
private void guardarImagemDiscoDoPreviewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Converter source da imagem num byte array
        byte[] ImageData = getJPGFromImageControl(previewImage.Source as BitmapImage);

        //Save As Dialog ...
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = "imagem";
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg";
        dlg.Filter = "Imagem JPEG|*.jpg";
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        //Gravar a imagem no disco
        using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(ImageData)))
        {
            image.Save(dlg.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);  // Ou Png ...
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Nenhuma imagem foi ainda carregada.", "ERRO!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

    }
}
```

Claro que isto resolve o meu problema mas não responde à questão inicial.